# export the variable from promise then block

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am new to the react.js and javascript world.

I have a promise object called `articles`, and I want to `export default` the variable `post` inside (or outside) the `then` block.

Approach 1:

```js
articles.then((response) => {

  let posts = response.map(...);

}, (error) => {

  console.log(error);

});

export default posts;  // undefined;
```

Approach 2:

```js
let posts;
articles.then((response) => {

  posts = response.map(...);

}, (error) => {

  console.log(error);

});

export default posts;  // undefined;
```

Approach 3:

```js
articles.then((response) => {

  export let posts = response.map(...); // Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

}, (error) => {

  console.log(error);

});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you tell me what is article ?

Comment: Please read a little bit about concurrency and you will understand why it doesn't make sense to try to export this. The reason #1 doesn't work is because it is locally scoped, #2 doesn't work because the export executes before the Promise does and the default value gets exported which is ```undefined```. #3 .. well so many things wrong with that. You should wrap this inside a function and export the function which will return a Promise, whoever is using the function can later resolve the promise as they wish

Comment: You can just export the promise chain instead.